# Galaxy S keeps accidentally taking screenshot

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, audio, screenshots

Galaxy S on 2.2 supports taking screenshots by holding the back button and tapping the home button simultaneously. However I find my phone occasionally doing it when I only tap the back or only the home button (which I do a lot).

This is inconvenient, but I don't mind too much it taking screenshots, but the bigger problem problem for me is the fact it makes a camera sound. This makes it sound like you just took a picture, and in public spaces it can land you in some embarassing situation. People might think you're a stalker, creep, or in some situation I think you can accidentally got into a fight or problem with police (I haven't landed in any of these situations, luckily). But it's quite dangerous.

Does anyone have the same problem? How to stop this or at least turn off the sound (other than putting my phone on silent mode)

Comment: I've had this happen a couple times.  Sometimes when the phone lags button presses get delayed, so pressing back then home can get smushed into being back PLUS home.  I wonder if using a custom ROM with TouchWiz removed would help.  That might remove the functionality entirely, actually.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s/341718-return-back-soft-key-not-working.html):

Go to the phone application on your phone and enter the following:

```
*#*#2663#*#*
```

It will take you to the Touch screen version screen.  Click on the "Touch key FW update" button on that screen.

Comment: what is this supposed to do?

Comment: It updates the Touch Key firmware.

Comment: from where? directly from Samsung?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where it gets that from.

Comment: can you cite a source? so that I can be sure I won't be breaking my phone..

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that earlier:  http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s/341718-return-back-soft-key-not-working.html

Comment: One guy in the thread says it worked, one other says it broke his keys entirely.  That doesn't sound promising.

Comment: Well, I performed those steps on my phone, when I had that problem, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings -> Applications -> Running Services` and click on `ScreenCaptureService` to end it.  You'll have to do this every time you boot up your phone, unless you get a task killer or can remove it somehow, though either of those may have other side effects.