# Why does my power button take screenshots?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread, screenshots

I haven't installed any screenshot applications, in fact my phone was recently wiped when upgrading to gingerbread. I have Gingerbread 2.3.4 and I use the GoLauncher homescreen. Samsung Mesmerize from US Cellular. I know they install bloatware but I've used this phone for months and it only did this after the upgrade to gingerbread (that I know of).

On occasion when I hit the power button the screen turns white and the phone vibrates, and I get a toast message saying "screen captured saved as image file" or something like that. Half the time the power button does that, half the time it turns off the screen normally. Right this second I couldn't replicate, it's very random and frustrating. What could cause this? I see no unusual running apps unless GoLauncher is doing this, and I see no setting related to this in their app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you hold the Home key and tap Power, it takes a screenshot.  Unfortunately sometimes lag causes the Home press to be delayed/extended, so if you press it and let go before hitting Power it will still happen sometimes.

The original SGS [suffers from this issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11068/galaxy-s-keeps-accidentally-taking-screenshot) as well, though it uses Home+Back.  I would try the same workaround I propose in my answer to that question:

> Go to `Settings -> Applications -> Running Services` and click on `ScreenCaptureService` to end it.  You'll have to do this every time you boot up your phone, unless you get a task killer or can remove it somehow, though either of those may have other side effects.

Comment: It appears to be the back key that does it on my phone, but that helps at least, thanks. A very annoying feature I never heard of...

Answer (score -1):

Hold your home button and your power button at the same time. Then hit the power button then it will lock it. It works just fine.